# Where has the hotkey for "Insert" -> "Cross-reference" gone in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I use cross-references a lot when writing documents in LibreOffice. I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 (can't remember the LO version, sorry), but I used to be able to do "Alt-i", "e" to get the cross reference dialog. Now, under Ubuntu 14.04, LO version 4.2.7.2 there is no hotkey for "Cross-reference" on the "Insert" menu. The "e" is no longer underlined and I cannot access the function from the keyboard without using the arrow keys on the "Insert" menu, which is super-annoying.

Is this me, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the way it is in the new version.  As I use cross-references a lot, I never even noticed because I've got a short-cut key defined for that: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

- Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> then <kbd>Customise</kbd> and click on the <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> tab.
- Navigate to the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as in the above screenshot
- Click category "Insert", function "Cross-reference"
- Hit <kbd>Modify</kbd> and then <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: Well, I like your solution, and your clear answer made it easy for me to implement, so I have (and I will use it for ever more ;) ). However, I don't get why they dropped the 'e' hotkey from the insert menu. They kept other items, just like in the old version of LO, it seems like "Cross-reference" was the only one they killed. Seems weird to me.

Comment: I dunno either.  Like I said: I only noticed when you told me...  ;-)